# React unable to rerender after setState using Fetch

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, render, setstate

I'm at my wits end. I'm a coding novice trying to use .map() to iterate through JSON data and display it in a card on React.

I fetch the data under componentDidMount() and use setState to assign it. This works completely fine on another page.

However, on this page I am trying to iterate through the 'projects' array on this object, but whenever I try to .map() into the products array I get errors.

Even with a simple `console.log` I get errors.

I think this has to do with asynchronous fetching but all the questions I see address this with setState(). I don't know what to do.

Here is my JSON object:

```
    {
    "_id": "59dac308b9267fbcb5d2de32",
    "name": "The Jewelry Counter",
    "description": "Limited edition fine jewelry, handcrafted in the USA",
    "image": "/public/images/tjclogo.png",
    "__v": 0,
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "59dada32b9267fbcb5d2de37",
            "name": "Opal and cubic zirconia stacking ring set",
            "price": 80,
            "description": "A three ring stacking set that features an arced ring with an opal and cz, one with just glowing cz's and one with a single solitaire prong set opal.",
            "img": "/shopping-cart-app/public/images/ringset.png",
            "quantity": 2,
            "__v": 0,
            "keywords": [
                "ring",
                "opal",
                "cubic zirconia",
                "cz",
                "jewelry",
                "womens",
                "jewelry counter"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "59dadae1b9267fbcb5d2de38",
            "name": "Moonstone Ear Jackets",
            "price": 140,
            "description": "Four teardrop shaped glowing moonstones are prong set and attach to your ear in a simple three piece process that makes it look as though they are floating on your ears.",
            "img": "/shopping-cart-app/public/images/moonearrings.png",
            "quantity": 4,
            "__v": 0,
            "keywords": [
                "earrings",
                "moonstone",
                "jewelry",
                "womens",
                "jewelry counter"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "59dadb79b9267fbcb5d2de39",
            "name": "Horizontal Pyrite Necklace",
            "price": 52,
            "description": "A horizontal bar of hand crushed pyrite is attached to a brass bar on a 16\" brass chain.",
            "img": "/shopping-cart-app/public/images/pyritenecklace.jpg",
            "quantity": 1,
            "__v": 0,
            "keywords": [
                "necklace",
                "pyrite",
                "jewelry",
                "womens",
                "jewelry counter"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "59dadcfbb9267fbcb5d2de3a",
            "name": "Purple Tourmaline Promise Rings",
            "price": 48,
            "description": "Faceted purple tourmaline prong set on an 18K yellow gold vermeil band. This simple ring is perfect for stacking.",
            "img": "/shopping-cart-app/public/images/ring.jpg",
            "quantity": 1,
            "__v": 0,
            "keywords": [
                "ring",
                "tourmaline",
                "jewelry",
                "womens",
                "jewelry counter"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StoreCard from '../../StoreCard';
import ProductCard from '../../ProductCard';
import Wrapper from '../../Wrapper';
import Header from '../../Header';
import StoreLogin from "../../StoreLogin";
import Store from "../../Store";
import './Shop.css';

class Shop extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { storeInfo: []};

    }

    // state = {storeInfo: [], 
        // products: []
    // };

   componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/stores/59dac308b9267fbcb5d2de32')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((storeInfo) => {this.setState({ storeInfo: storeInfo })})
   }






  render() {
    console.log(this.state.storeInfo) // works,displays the entire JSON object after beig called twice in the console.
    console.log(this.state.storeInfo.name); // WORKS, same as above
    console.log(this.state.storeInfo['products'][1]['name']); //DOES NOT WORK - ERRORS
    // console.log(this.state.storeInfo.products[1].name); //DOES NOT WORK - ERRORS

    return (
     <div>
        <Header location="Search all stores"/>
        <Wrapper>

          <StoreLogin
            id={this.state.storeInfo._id} // works
            userName={this.state.storeInfo.name} // works
            // productName={this.state.storeInfo.products[1].name} //does not work
          >






            </StoreLogin>

      </Wrapper>
      <h1>Shop</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Shop;
```

When I uncomment the 'console.logs' and the 'productName' in the storeLogin component one at a time, I get 3 errors:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

Then

```
proxyConsole.js:54 The above error occurred in the <Shop> component:
    in Shop (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:22)
    in div (at App.js:19)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:17)
    in App (at index.js:6)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
You can learn more about error boundaries at https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html
```

And then

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

again.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Why are you initializing `storeInfo` as empty array when the fetch results in a single Object?

Comment: @pritesh I updated my original question to display my errors, thanks for your time!

Comment: @RamanKumarSharma I thought I had to because it is an object and not a string, thank you for pointing out that I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is data you are trying to access storeInfo['products'][1]['name'] is not yet available in the render function initially.So you need to check if data is present.For that what you can do is

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.storeInfo.name); // WORKS

    //Move this console inside if
    if ( this.state.storeInfo.products && this.state.storeInfo.products.length) {
        console.log(this.state.storeInfo['products'][1]['name']);
        console.log(this.state.storeInfo.products[0].name); 
    }

    return (
    <div>
        <Header location="Search all stores"/>
        <Wrapper>

        <StoreLogin
            id={this.state.storeInfo._id} // works
            userName={this.state.storeInfo.name} // works
             productName={this.state.storeInfo.products && this.state.storeInfo.products.length &&
 this.state.storeInfo.products[0].name} //<-- Same here
        >
        </StoreLogin>
    </Wrapper>
    <h1>Shop</h1>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Pritesh! You are a lifesaver! This works. Is there anyway to put this into a .map() method? Like `{this.state.storeInfo.products.map(product)  => < iPutMyCardInHere /> }`

Comment: yes you can do like this `this.state.storeInfo.products.map((product) => < iPutMyCardInHere />)`

Comment: Oh hallelujah! I got it to work. I don't understand why I have to do this if the component should rerender after the state is set? Does it just take too long?

Comment: For anyone looking: 
`{this.state.storeInfo.products && this.state.storeInfo.products.length &&
 this.state.storeInfo.products.map((product)  =><iPutMyCardInHere />)}`
allowed me to pass my props as `product.keyName` in the card.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you are having a fetchRequest in the componentDidMount function and then setting the state, however your render is called before it and since you try to access `this.state.storeInfo.products[0].name`, `this.state.storeInfo.products` is undefined and hence you get an error, do a check before using it

```
return (
 <div>
    <Header location="Search all stores"/>
    <Wrapper>

      <StoreLogin
        id={this.state.storeInfo._id} // works
        userName={this.state.storeInfo.name} // works
        productName={this.state.storeInfo.products && his.state.storeInfo.products[0]?
         this.state.storeInfo.products[0].name: ''} 
      >
```